# Why is EJB remotely accessible and Servlet not

Tags: java, servlets, ejb

I was trying to understand the difference between EJB and Servlet (I know both are conceptually different, EJB is a piece of Java Code with some rules and Servlet is something that accepts and processes HTTP requests) But I found that one of the difference between the two is also:

Ejbs allows Remote Accessing.
Servlet/jsp's does not allow remote accessing

I do not understand the above difference. Why an EJB can be remotely accessible and Servlet not.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet responds to http request (normaly) note that a JSP is transformed to a servler. A EJB it's totaly diferent, EJB define your business model. 
It seems you are confused about what remote accessing is, it means that you can have a EJB deployed in a different server running in a different JVM and that your servlets can access it. 
In the other side you can have local EJBs which run in the same server has the rest of your webapp and in the same JVM as your servlets and jsps. Depending on whether you EJB is local or remote the implementation differs in some little aspects (in remote EJBs you need to create an interface and other things, I won't enter in details, I'll add a link about this).

If you want to understand what's the difference between servlets, jsps and ebjs, you should understand what MVC (Model View Controller) is. Normally Controller is defined by servlets, which receive the http request from the client and delegate the actions that they do in EJBs and JSPs. The View is defined by JSPs ( I assume you already understand what they are). And EJBs are the Model, they define your business model, they don't serve http requests, they just perform simple actions over your "model" like update/select/insert data in your database, and many other things.

See more in:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-intro.htm#GIJSZ for EJB

Also I recomend you the following two books:

Head First Servlets and JSP  http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005405.do

Head First EJB http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005719.do

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, but it still doesnt answer my question, and i know what remote access is, but i just want to know why is it said that EJB's can be accessed remotely and not servlets/jsp's

Comment: Are you sure they cant ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164822/calling-a-remote-java-servlet

Comment: I am actually not. I don't know why people have written on a lot of forums that Servlet's cannot be accessed remotely and EJB's can